# SSRS Change Row Color for First Row of Sorting

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a table that is sorted by Main Tank and would like to make the first row of each sort (where the name of main tank switches to a new tank) to be grey.  So if you have 10 rows with only 2 tanks you would have two lines of gray, the first for each new tank.  I though I could possibly use RunningValue for this but haven't been able to get that to work.  Any suggestions on a function or method I could use for this?

Comment: Detail how your tablix is set in order to help you. Do you have Row Groups?

Comment: No groups, just a sorting set under the tablix properties --> sorting tab.  Had it set with grouping because that would have made it simple but the client didn't like it that way for no real reason :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve that checking if the current value is equal to the previous, in that case you set the background-color the color you want.

I've used this table to test.

[image]

Select the row, in Background-color property use this expression:

```
=iif(
Fields!Tank.Value=previous(Fields!Tank.Value),
"Transparent",
"Red"
)
```

Replace `"Red"` for the color you want.

It will produce something like this:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks.  I wasn't aware you could do something as simple as "previous".

Comment: The customer changed how they want this now, they would like in your example the A tanks to both be red, then the B tanks to be white, then the C tanks red etc.  Can this be done without grouping?

Comment: @Aerobane , If my answer solved your problem when you posted your question, why did you deselect my answer as correct? When your requeriments have been changed (completely in this case) it should be explained in another question. Also if you notify your new issue using comments I am the only one who knows that, it could not have the whole community visibility required to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add a partitioned `ROW_NUMBER()` to the dataset and use it in the background color expression for the row to set the color to gray when the `row number = 1`.

Comment: Wont that only change the background of row 1, not the first row of every new sort?

Comment: Not if you use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Tank)`  That's what I mean by Partitioned ROW_NUMBER().